# Delete row on sms.db iOS 6

Tags: iphone, database, sms, jailbreak

I want to delete a row in many tables: `chat`, `handle` in [sms.db](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IMessage) on iOS6. It seems to work perfectly but actually does **not**.

Example: If I want to delete a row with ROWID = 123 in the `handle` table, the delete worked, but in `handle` table, another row appears exactly with the row I deleted but ROWID is **124** (not 123).

Does anyone know why?

Comment: are u testing in iPhone Simulator??

Comment: No, Im test on my Jailbroken phone